# Selenium python choose date on a date picker field?

Tags: python, selenium

**How do I change the date by manually clicking them? I've tried changing it via js it does change the date but when I submit it it'll go back to the default date.**

```
self.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName")
self.execute_script("var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = '26-08-2022';", date)
```

---

**The date field needed to be clicked each manually in order to change them.**

[image: I've tried changing the date directly but sadly I didn't work]

```
    <div layout="" layout-align="center center" ng-repeat-start="day in calendar.daysInMonth track by $index" ng-class="{ 'mdp-day-placeholder': !day }" class="ng-scope layout-align-center-center layout-row"><!-- ngIf: day --><button class="md-icon-button md-raised md-button ng-scope md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="Select day" ng-if="day" ng-class="{ 'md-accent': calendar.date.date() == day.value }" ng-click="calendar.selectDate(day.value);datepicker.confirm()" ng-disabled="!day.enabled" disabled="disabled"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">1</span></button><!-- end ngIf: day --></div>
```

**Each numbers has a button to change the day of the calendar**

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" class="layout-align-space-between-center layout-row"><button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="previous months" ng-click="calendar.prevMonth()"><ng-md-icon icon="keyboard_arrow_left" class="ng-scope"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path d="M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon></button><div class="mdp-calendar-monthyear ng-binding" ng-show="!calendar.animating" aria-hidden="false">August 2022</div><button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="next month" ng-click="calendar.nextMonth()"><ng-md-icon icon="keyboard_arrow_right" class="ng-scope"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path d="M8.59 16.34l4.58-4.59-4.58-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon></button></div>
```

**This html is a two button to change the month on the calendar**

```
<div class="md-dialog-container ng-scope"
```

**This is the div that contains the calendar, I only included the class attribute**

Comment: Can you share the site, or the code behind the calendar picker? It's difficult to help without that information.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Do I need to add the whole code or just the simplified one?

Comment: @Potatomanl you need to add the `@` whilest replying elese we aren't notified to whomsoever you are replying.

Comment: @Potatomanl HTML of the datepicker is the bare minimum.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium like this?

Comment: @Potatomanl yoo, comment like that, perfect but you still need to provide a better HTML.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium https://pastebin.com/Zmt9atX3